# Why using useRef in this react example? just for concept demostration?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Just wonder what purpose the useRef serve here in example: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables:

```
function Timer() {
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // ...
    });
    intervalRef.current = id;
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    };
  });

  // ...
  function handleCancelClick() {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }
  // ...
}
```

I tried and can achieve the same without useRef as below:

```
function Timer() {
  const interval = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // ...
    });
    interval = id;
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  // ...
  function handleCancelClick() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  // ...
}
```

So the saying "but it’s useful if we want to clear the interval from an event handler" from the react doc and this answer: [Is useRef Hook a must to set and clear intervals in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914921/is-useref-hook-a-must-to-set-and-clear-intervals-in-react), just mean almost nothing at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is useRef Hook a must to set and clear intervals in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914921/is-useref-hook-a-must-to-set-and-clear-intervals-in-react)

Comment: The answer is not useful at all. My code has shown that a normal variable can do the job without useRef. Both the example code and my modified version has a useEffect clear-up that takes care of a re-render situation already.

Comment: I guess that it wants to preserve the interval id between **renders**

Comment: That indeed is a purpose useRef can serve. Though the example don't seem to need it for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine only if you don't want stopping timer in `handleCancelClick` and keep all logic inside single `useEffect`(which would be really rare case).

See, if you get any re-render(because of any `useState` entry changed or props changed) between running timer and `handleCancelClick` you will get that variable `const interval = null;` and nothing will happen on click(`clearTimeout(null);` does nothing).

Don't see how that can be handled without preserving data between renders.

Comment: clearTimeout(null)??? https://codepen.io/peterhung101/pen/VwwqMpa

Comment: oh, right, in your case you have `useEffect` to run on each render. But in real case you run timer _in some_ cases. Just add some dependincies to `useEffect`. `[]` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks ... perhaps that where I got confused the react doc's example - using useRef for no obvious reason since the effect is running on each render